# Directx 11 Front Buffer

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directx-10, dxgi

I am hoping this is a easy answer to an easy question which I cannot find an answer to.

How do I access the front buffer in Directx 11 / DXGI? I have found in Directx 9 you can use GetFrontBufferData() and you can use GetBuffer() in Directx 11 to get access to the backbuffer but there are problems with this. The backbuffer doesn't have calculations done to it that the front buffer does.

So I was wondering if there is something I am missing.

I could try using GetDisplaySurfaceData and unless I have mis-understood something then it wouldn't work because I am not always in full-screen mode.

Edit: Could someone let me know how the GetBuffer works in SwapChain for Directx 11. As I have read that antialiasing only occurs on the front buffer and never a backbuffer. Is 0 the first backbuffer? (Microsoft state that you can only use 0 in certain instances.)

Is it possible at all to get the Front Buffer in Directx 11?

Many thanks,

Comment: Why do you need the front buffer at all? Almost all rendering operations you can do, aside from AA, are done on the back buffer.

Comment: Because I want the AA.

Comment: When the swap chain is created you can specify multisampling, which will allow you to turn on MSAA. If you don't want MSAA, you can create the swap chain without multisampling and set AntialiasedLineEnable to true in the rasterizer state for the device. If neither of these work for you, disable automatic antialiasing, render your whole scene, then get the backbuffer and do AA through a custom shader. Other than that, there's not much else you can do. See [the community content here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer` API to retrieve a swap chain surface ( use the uuid `ID3D11Texture2D` for the result type ).

Now, the swap chain buffers are not mapable, so you need to copy it to a staging resource.

- Use `ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc` to retrieve the surface description
- Patch it with a `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` usage and a cpu access flag of `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ`
- Create a temporary surface `ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D`
- Copy to the staging surface `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource`

You now have a `ID3D11Texture2D` with the content of your swap chain buffer that allow you to use the `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` API to read it on the CPU

Comment: As I understand that is the back buffer, or am I mistaken. If that is not the backbuffer where is the backbuffer?

Comment: The front buffer is not accessible with DXGI. It is rare to render to the back buffer directly and let the swap chain resolve the multisampling anyway. Create a single sample swap chain and an additional multi sample framebuffer, then call `ID3D11DeviceContext::ResolveSubresource` to merge the samples to the back buffer then do what i explain to dump it before presentation.

Comment: When reading Microsoft, it states that only the FrontBuffer has been antialiased. Is this no longer true?

Comment: The swap chain is able to resolve a multi sample back buffer to a single sample front buffer for you and may also do some scaling to fit the image to the window. When you depends on an automatic service, it is common to loose control. That is the reason to do things by yourself, it lets you render some non antialiased surface like 2D interfaces after the `ResolveSubresource` call or with a manual full screen quad with a custom shader to merge fragments as you want.