# Extract the texture using DirectX from the GPU

Tags: c++, node.js, gpu, extract

And so I need a c ++ script that will extract a specific texture and save it to disk in a given place, I was looking on the internet, but I can't find anything like that. I would add that I would like to combine it with the nodejs script, but priority is what I wrote sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar answer.
[Directx 11 Front Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459004/directx-11-front-buffer)
It extracts a Texture2D and for some it is the Main Frame from the Swap Chain.

Comment: I know it is the technique to share own game play video to share.